# Select multiple shipping methods on Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout, shipping-method

I'm trying to select multiple shipping methods on Stripe Checkout but only one shipping method is possible to select:

[image]

Are there any ways to select multiple shipping methods on Stripe Checkout?

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: Like amazon online shopping, I want to set different shipping addresses and methods to each product in one order. On amazon, we can select different shipping addresses and methods to each product in one order but it seems like stripe can select only one shipping address and method to all products in one order.

Comment: Got it. I'd recommend relaying your feedback to Stripe directly via [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact).

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to select multiple shipping options on the hosted Checkout page. This is limited to 1.